# Toolbar cannot be converted to int Androidx

Tags: android, android-toolbar

When I try to build my project I get this error:

> incompatible types: Toolbar cannot be converted to int

I Found much similar questions but they were not helpful to me 
I work with this Library:

> import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

And this is my code

```
package com.majaxtn.codingup;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import androidx.legacy.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import static com.majaxtn.codingup.R.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;

    private boolean isAdmin=false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef=database.getReference();
        myRef.child("admins").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.child(auth.getUid()).exists()&&dataSnapshot.child(auth.getUid()).getValue().toString().equals("true"))
                    isAdmin=true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, string.navigation_drawer_open, string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_test) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Tests.class));
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_result) {
            if(isAdmin)
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,ResultsAdmin.class));
            else startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,Results.class));
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_respass) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_signout) {
            auth.signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_details) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddDetails.class));
        } else if(id==R.id.about_details){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,AboutUsActivity.class));
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And below is screen with my problem

[Screenshot with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8rIK.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this import line -> import androidx.legacy.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

Try using this -> import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;